# Items bind to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yynjh.png)

When viewing the code in the browser window Header:

```
<h1>Music</h1>
<h2>w</h2>
<h2>a</h2>
<h2>s</h2>
<h2>d</h2>
<h2>z</h2>
<h2>x</h2>
<h2>C</h2>
```

do not appear on the page, I do not understand why? I wrote different versions of the code, I referred to them in js through element.innerHTML, etc., the elements appear, BUT then the audio does not sound. Can anyone help? Need an array for these elements in js?
Thanks in advance for your reply.

```
  </head>
  <body id='audios'>
  <div class="container">
       <h1>Music</h1>
      <h2>Q</h2>
      <button id="play">Play</button>
      <button id="pause">Pause</button>     
      <h2>W</h2>
      <button id="play">Play</button>
      <button id="pause">Pause</button>     
      <h2>E</h2>
      <button id="play">Play</button>
      <button id="pause">Pause</button> 
      <h2>A</h2>
      <button id="play">Play</button>
      <button id="pause">Pause</button>

//$(document).ready(function(){
 //  $("h1").html("Hello world!")
 //});

var addresses = ["https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Kick_n_Hat.mp3", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-6.mp3", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Dsc_Oh.mp3", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/RP4_KICK_1.mp3", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Cev_H2.mp3", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Chord_1.mp3", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Chord_2.mp3", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Chord_3.mp3",  "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Give_us_a_light.mp3"];
var body = document.getElementById("audios");
let audiohtml = [];
addresses.map((address, i)=> {
  audiohtml.push(`<audio id='myAudio${i}' src=${address} preload='auto'></audio>

<button onClick=togglePlay(${i})>Play</button>
<button onClick=togglePause(${i})>Pause</button>`)
});
body.innerHTML= audiohtml;
function togglePlay(i) {
    var myAudio = document.getElementById(`myAudio${i}`);
    myAudio.play();
};
function togglePause(i) {
    var myAudio = document.getElementById(`myAudio${i}`);
    myAudio.pause()
};
```

Comment: i don't see any `C`s in your code

Comment: You are wondering why the code that is in the container is not there after it runs? (You overwrite it)

Comment: epascarello 
Yes, you are right, it is not after launch

Comment: Only English on this site, please. You might have better luck on [ru.so]...